# How to make this Modal scrollable?

Tags: jquery, sass, modal-dialog, scrollable

Hi there I've been struggling quite a bit on how to make this modal scrollable. I've tried everything written out there similar to my issue. I want it to contain my terms and conditions that I want the user to scroll through.

```
            <div id="modal-container">
                <div class="modal-background">
                    <div class="modal" style="overflow:scroll;">
                        <div class="termsandconditions">

                        <h3>Terms of Use</h3>
                        <p>By subscribing you are willing to...</p>
                        <p>...</p>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

This is the exact code https://jsfiddle.net/hghazni/jxy3fx0x/1/

And this is the live version if you want to look at the whole thing (it's in the 'leave a review' section) once you click the Terms and conditions link.

http://bodyondemand.co.uk

I appreciate it any help in making the modal scrollable!

Comment: Fiddle has a bunch of issues including no button to trigger the modal. Get that working or provide a MCVE here https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve if you would like help.

Comment: Can you show us how you implement your scrolling function? The problem is in the scrolling function if not mistaken.

Comment: The problem is that there are far too many dependencies to start putting a working modal in JS fiddle (I've just tried even with all the code in). The live version is probably the best way to look at everything. Also I've not currently implemented a scrolling function. I tried to add overflow: scroll; to the .termsandconditions div by setting an exact height and width over the parent modal but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To scroll the content you need to set height for `<div class="modal">` element. You already set `overflow:scroll` which is not enough,

Here's the place you need to update,

```
 $('#modal-container').removeAttr('class').addClass(buttonId).find('.modal').height($(window).outerHeight(true));
```

You didn't give us proper working fiddle and it has some issues, I made it work based on assumption. Here's the updated fiddle to test, https://jsfiddle.net/jxy3fx0x/8/

Comment: Thanks Muthu, that did the trick and unfortunately because the modal appears in an overlay page over the index.html it's quite hard to fit into the jsfiddle.